# add namespace to locale files dynamically

Tags: botframework

I'm having some trouble with getText because in different libraries it could exist the same keyText with different value.

I realized that I can use namespace to load their own text ,but I can't find a way to do it different from changing the key of each stringValue.

Some idea?

Example:

Actual locales:

libOne/locale/en/index.json

```
{
  "libName": "LibOne"
}
```

libTwo/locale/en/index.json

```
{
  "libName": "LibTwo"
}
```

To get the text:

```
session.localizer.gettext(session.preferredLocale(), "libName");
```

To be able to have at two libraries a text with the same key I've realised that I can use namespaces:

libOne/locale/en/index.json

```
{
  "libOne:libName": "libOne"
}
```

libTwo/locale/en/index.json

```
{
  "libTwo:libName": "libTwo"
}
```

To get the text:

```
session.localizer.gettext(session.preferredLocale(), "libName", "libOne");
session.localizer.gettext(session.preferredLocale(), "libName", "libTwo");
```

As a temporal solution I've add the namespace to each key for each lib, but I think that should be some way to do it without changing manually all the keys for example:

```
{
  "libOne": {
    "libName": "libOne"
  }
}
```

Instead of:

```
{
  "libOne:libName": "libOne"
}
```

Comment: This is a bit vague. Could you specify with an example or a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to make it really easy, instead of adding the namespace before ":", the namespace can be added changing the filename.

For the example above:

libOne/locale/en/libOne.json

```
{
  "libName": "libOne"
}
```

libTwo/locale/en/libTwo.json

```
{
  "libName": "libTwo"
}
```

To get the text:

```
session.localizer.gettext(session.preferredLocale(), "libName", "libOne");
session.localizer.gettext(session.preferredLocale(), "libName", "libTwo");
```